# Pandas - Check which column match another column - not boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
target     A       B      C
0 cat      bridge  cat    brush
1 brush    dog     cat    shoe
2 bridge   cat     shoe   bridge
```

Desired output:

```
  target   A       B      C       D
0 cat      bridge  cat    brush   B
1 brush    dog     cat    shoe    None
2 bridge   cat     shoe   bridge  C
```

I need to know which column match my target column (col D). I have seen the previous post 43093394, but it's not enough for me to know if the columns match or not, i need to know which column match which target, and if none match. The same problem is posted here 40320476, but in sql so it didn't help me.

Looking forward to your input, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `eq` with `dot`

```
df.loc[:,'A':].eq(df.target,0).dot(df.columns[1:])
Out[466]: 
0    B
1     
2    C
dtype: object
#df['D']=df.loc[:,'A':].eq(df.target,0).dot(df.columns[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! Can you tell me why I can't insert specific column names ex. ['A','F'] instead of 'A':  to optimize my search. Normally it works using loc, so why not in this case, and do you have an alternative?

Comment: @sand then you should do df[ ['A','F'] ]

Answer (score 2):

These solutions will return the first column that matches if any.

#### `idxmax`

```
m = df.drop('target', 1).eq(df.target, axis=0)
df.assign(D=m.idxmax(1).where(m.any(1)))

   target       A     B       C    D
0     cat  bridge   cat   brush    B
1   brush     dog   cat    shoe  NaN
2  bridge     cat  shoe  bridge    C
```

---

#### `np.where`

```
t = df.target.values[:, None]
v = df.drop('target', 1)
m = t == v.values

i = np.where(m.any(1), v.columns[m.argmax(1)], np.nan)

df.assign(D=i)

   target       A     B       C    D
0     cat  bridge   cat   brush    B
1   brush     dog   cat    shoe  NaN
2  bridge     cat  shoe  bridge    C
```

Answer (score 0):

For your basic understanding I have done something below but I recommend you to use other experts answers because they are more generic.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['cat', 'bridge','cat','brush'], ['brush','dog','cat','shoe'], ['bridge','cat','shoe','bridge' ]], columns=['target','A', 'B','C'])
mapper = {0:'A',1:'B',2:'C'}
func = lambda x : mappr[[x['A'],x['B'],x['C']].index(x['target'])] if x['target'] in [x['A'],x['B'],x['C']] else np.nan
df['D'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
df
```

output

```
   target   A   B   C   D
0   cat bridge  cat brush   B
1   brush   dog cat shoe    NaN
2   bridge  cat shoe    bridge  C
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually thinking about something like that myself as my last resort, as I have solved problems like that in R before. But for this problem I need something more generic, as  you say.
Just started using pandas, so I'm not very strong with the functions yet. 
But thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I knew and that's why I suggest you to see the documentation and have fun learning pandas + numpy.